# How to convert NSArray to integer values

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my iPhone by applying below code I am able to get value of "i"

```
NSMutableArray *Array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++) {          
    id a = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:i];
    [Array addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:a, @"a", nil]];
 }
```

But if I want to get value from array like as an example

```
NSArray * numberArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0.1",@"0.2",@"0.5",nil];
```

and then if I want to use it as

```
NSMutableArray *Array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++) {          
    id a = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[numberArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [Array addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:a, @"a", nil]];
 }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

I don't really understand but I'll try to help you.

If you want to store Integers into a NSArray use this code to set and get them :

```
// Set
NSArray *yourArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],nil];

// Get
int currentNumber;
for(int i=0; i<[yourArray count]; i++)
{
    currentNumber = [((NSNumber*)[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]) intValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you start with this array, whose content is made of `NSString` objects (@"0.1" is a string):

```
NSArray * numberArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0.1",@"0.2",@"0.5",nil];
```

the you can scan each element using this loop:

```
for(NSString *strNum in numberArray) {
  float number = [strNum floatValue];
  NSLog(@"Number: %f",float);
}
```

the string to float conversion is possible thanks to the `floatValue()` method of `NSString`.

You can use doubleValue, longLongValue, integerValue for other types. These methods will return 0 if no valid number representation is given with the string.